# What is the name of the grammatical construct that expresses a "loophole" in a requirement?

Tags: phrases

Is there a grammatical term for "loophole" phrase? By "loophole" I mean a phrase that weakens or conditions the main clause. Examples:

1. The system shall calculate aircraft altitude, when necessary.
2. If possible, the contractor shall report progress every month.
3. As much as possible, the system shall display aircraft speed.

Loopholes: "when necessary"  "If possible"  "As much as possible"

I'm writing a manual for people writing engineering requirements. I want writers to avoid "loopholes" such as those in the example above. But I'd like to use a correct grammatical term for the "loophole."

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I do not understand what grammar has to do with logic and reason.

Comment: That's easy. Grammar is a set of rules of a language that people use to express logic and reason. Grammar bad is when used people unable to understand are. But I didn't ask about logic and reason. I just asked whether anyone knows the name of the grammatical construct I gave, e.g., "subordinate clause" or "non-restrictive relative clause" or similar term.

Comment: What you describe is not really a grammatical category. But you could call it a "limiting adverbial constituent".

Answer (score 3):

"Hedge".  A hedge is tacked on to qualify a phrase as being perhaps not 100% true or not 100% appropriate.  As for example, if I qualified my answer by writing "'hedge', to a certain extent, at any rate".

Answer (score 1):

You could discourage your audience from using:

> **qualifying language**,

especially that which includes "[qualifiers of possibility](http://changingminds.org/techniques/language/modifying_meaning/qualifiers.htm)," in their descriptions of the engineering requirements ([e.g.?], [whenever possible](http://www.nash-law.com/article-9-the-most-commonly-vi/rss.xml)).

See also, the bottom of page 7 for another example of its use with "[whenever possible.](http://www.sec.gov/divisions/corpfin/cf-noaction/14a-8/2012/tommygrooms100212-14a8.pdf)"

Regarding your example #2, as it is written it certainly reads as an example of "loophole/hedge(from Greg's great answer)/qualifying" language, but I think that it might have another interpretation that could be clarified as follows:

2. The contractor shall report progress every month, and for any month in which no progress is made, this fact shall likewise be reported and fully explained.